Are we epistemically inclined to believe whatever we want in philosophy?
By any belief, I of course do still mean beliefs that are internally consistent, since it would obviously make no sense to believe in square triangles.
As per wikipedia,
In epistemology, the Münchhausen trilemma is a thought experiment intended to demonstrate the theoretical impossibility of proving any truth, even in the fields of logic and mathematics, without appealing to accepted assumptions. If it is asked how any given proposition is known to be true, proof in support of that proposition may be provided. Yet that same question can be asked of that supporting proof, and any subsequent supporting proof. The Münchhausen trilemma is that there are only three ways of completing a proof:

The circular argument, in which the proof of some proposition presupposes the truth of that very proposition


The regressive argument, in which each proof requires a further proof, ad infinitum


The dogmatic argument, which rests on accepted precepts which are merely asserted rather than defended
Does this give leeway to someone believing in anything?

For example, suppose a person has a hallucinogenic experience of seeing the devil in his room after taking LSD. He may take that as evidence that the devil is real who decided to reveal himself to him after a druglike experience. Another person may take that as evidence that he is hallucinating because of a drug and that the devil in his experience is not externally real. How can there be an objective way to handling disagreement here without relying upon standards of evidence that in and of themselves cannot be conclusively justified as per the trilemma?

Closely related, if not a dup: Are two persons equally rational in choosing different dogmatic stopping points in their chains of justification as per the Münchhausen trilemma?

For the more abstract point about philosophical methodology see also https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/119422/

No, if you don't postulate it dogmatically, MT always throws you back on yourself as a subject. You can only know that you cannot get out of yourself, which only brings you into conflict with classical realism if you think that things are as they appear, or if you postulate a pantheism with development (as Hegel does), since here you can override the subject/object separation and at the same time you cannot know whether other people really exist. MT refutes some philosophical positions, but Kant did this before, and it does not allow you to believe in everything or to question everything, which critical rationalists keep claiming in order to immunize Popper's approach itself. It does not have much philosophical relevance, but it does make it very easy to criticize certain positions, which makes it particularly important for laypeople to get their bearings.

Where does Hegel postulate pantheism? What is a pantheism "with development"?

He did not say direct that he postulates a pantheism with development, but that follows from him. Pantheism means that everything in the world is God. Here there is a pantheism without evolution (everything is God and does not change), or with evolution, that this "everything" continues to evolve.

How does it not allow you to question everything? Name something that it doesn’t allow you to question except perhaps consciousness or the reality of experience itself

You can't get out of yourself, how can you question that? Have you ever gotten out of your body?

It is an empirical fact that you cannot escape from your body. So how do you have access to the world? You can smell through your nose, you can see through your eyes, you can touch a stone with your hands. That is a fact. Between the world and the world lie your senses and you cannot question that, which makes classical realism impossible (Kant). So an apple is not red in itself, but an object in the subject that appears red.

@tenebrisinkux you can (technically) question whether your body even exists, and thus getting out of yourself may be a meaningless statement

@tenebris in kux what you are saying you cannot question is what I already alluded to when I said “except conscious experience.” So can you name anything apart from this that you can’t question?

Yes, you can, you can't refute a hard idealism, but if the world is real (assumption) and if you can't get out of your body, then... You can continue to research like that. If someone denies reality completely, including that they don't have a hand, that there is no stone, then you can do that, but it doesn't lead to anything. If you look at it that way, then empirical research is pointless.

@tenebrisinkux You say "He did not say direct that he postulates a pantheism with development, but that follows from him [Hegel]." How does it follow?

@Jo Wehler have a look on this:
"Das Wahre ist das Ganze. Das Ganze aber ist nur das durch seine Entwicklung sich vollendende Wesen. Es ist von dem Absoluten zu sagen, dass es wesentlich Resultat, dass es erst am Ende das ist, was es in Wahrheit ist; und hierin eben besteht seine Natur, Wirkliches, Subjekt oder Sichselbstwerden zu sein." Hegel

In english:
"The true is the whole. The whole, however, is only the essence that perfects itself through its development. It can be said of the Absolute that it is essentially a result, that it is only at the end what it is in truth; and this is precisely its nature, to be something real, subject, or becoming itself." Hegel

Could you please give a precise reference of the quote. - The quote speaks about "das Wahre", "das Ganze", "das Absolute". How does the quote relate to Hegel's view on pantheism?

Here you can read the context in original german: http://www.zeno.org/Philosophie/M/Hegel,+Georg+Wilhelm+Friedrich/Ph%C3%A4nomenologie+des+Geistes/Vorrede#google_vignette
The book is in english called "The Phenomenology of Spirit". As Hegel write, he postulate an a being that evolves, that being is God.

Here some more infos: "Hegelian philosophy and pantheism: Hegel distanced himself from pantheism, but that does not change the fact that he developed a pantheistic philosophy, as long as one sees the core of pantheism in the unity of God and being, of creator and creatures, etc. Hegel has a dialectical view of the identity and simultaneous non-identity of God and being, etc. and thus differs from other pantheists, without ceasing to be a pantheist himself. ."
http://www.philolex.de/hegel.htm

@tenebrisinkux It seems that your quote is from wikipedia. Just referring to the “Phaenomenologie des Geistes” is not a precise quote, the book has hundreds of pages. If you read a text in the original version you should be able to give a precise reference. – Secondly, I do not consider it my task to search in the whole book for a passage which supports your claim about the relation between Hegel and pantheism. – So we can stop at this point.

First, I have read the book. Second, what is unclair of the post above? Did you know what pantheism is? The quote can be found in the preface of the book. I can look up the exact page for you, but I have the book in the office.

You don’t have to look up a single passage, the whole work is structured in such a way that you will find it again and again in numerous places, I have only given one passage as an example,


The Muenchhausen trilemma does not prompt to arbitrary beliefs.
That's not its aim. The Muenchhausen trilemma illustrates that there
is no ultimate justification for general statements.
Popper draws the conclusion to continue with the search for good
answers, i.e. for theories supported by good arguments. But the theories
must be considered to be hypotheses. They have to be put to test, to
check whether they are confirmed or refuted.


If there is no ultimate justification for general statements, what makes one statement more justified than another? And if nothing does, then why does that not make every claim “equally” justified/unjustified?

The argumentation for each statement has to be considered, tested and assessed in separation.

Assessed based on what? @Jo Wehler how would those assessments be justified and escape the trilemma?

Popper really does claim that empirical hypotheses must always be able to be refuted on empirical grounds. But that is because he wanted to protect physics from dogmatic ideological systems that he sees in Hegel, Marx or Spengler. Does Popper himself see critical rationalism as truly philosophically proven? I suspect so. But it is not tenable, but critical rationalism is helpful for empirical researchers because they do not have to study epistemology, but can still work well. It is a pragmatic approach, a psychological attitude.

@tenerbrisinkux I do not know what you mean by "philosophically proven". Either a statement is proven or it is not. Popper does not consider fallibilism proven - proven statements are very rare, e.g., they exist in axiomatized theories. You may consider Popper's proposal a hypothesis. I haven't heard that it is refuted.

@Jo Wehler Do you have a quote from Popper where he really talks about that the   critical rationalism is a hypothesis? I remember him quite differently, but if there is such a quote, I'm happy to change my mind. Luhmann also criticizes him because he understands Popper to mean that he is talking about a real proof.

@tenebrisexkux See Karl Popper: Conjectures and Refutations, Chapter I, Section VII: "From the point of view here developed all laws, all theories, remain essentially tentative, or conjectural, or
hypothetical, even when we feel unable to doubt them any longer. Before a theory has been refuted we can never
know in what way it may have to be modified." Apply this passage to the theory of fallibilism or more general to critical rationalism.

"Apply this passage to the theory of fallibilism or more general to critical rationalism." Yes, but that only applies to empirical hypotheses. There are only empirical hypotheses or proofs under axioms (logic, mathematics) or under proven principles (philosophy). One can apply the theorem to Popper himself, but then Popper loses all impact against Hegel, Schopenhauer, etc.
